# Optimizing Python code - overhead due to pandas.core.series.Series.__getitem__

Tags: python, optimization, pandas

I have `pandas` data object - `data` - that is stored as Series of Series. The first series is indexed on `ID1` and the second on `ID2`.

```
ID1      ID2
1        10259           0.063979
         14166           0.120145
         14167           0.177417
         14244           0.277926
         14245           0.436048
         15021           0.624367
         15260           0.770925
         15433           0.918439
         15763           1.000000
...
1453     812690          0.752274
         813000          0.755041
         813209          0.756425
         814045          0.778434
         814474          0.910647
         814475          1.000000
Length: 19726, dtype: float64
```

I have a function that uses values from this object for further data processing. Here is the function:

```
#Function
def getData(ID1, randomDraw): 
    dataID2 = data[ID1]
    value = dataID2.index[np.searchsorted(dataID2, randomDraw, side='left').iloc[0]]
    return value
```

I use `np.vectorize` to apply this function on a `DataFrame` - `dataFrame` - that has about 22 million rows.

```
dataFrame['ID2'] = np.vectorize(getData)(dataFrame['ID1'], dataFrame['RAND'])
```

where `ID1` and `RAND` are columns with values that are feeding into the function.

The code takes about 6 hours to process everything. A similar implementation in `Java` takes only about 6 minutes to get through 22 million rows of data.

On running a profiler on my program I find that the most expensive call is the indexing into `data` and the second most expensive is `searchsorted`.

```
Function Name: pandas.core.series.Series.__getitem__
Elapsed inclusive time percentage: 54.44

Function Name: numpy.core.fromnumeric.searchsorted  
Elapsed inclusive time percentage: 25.49
```

Using `data.loc[ID1]` to get data makes the program even slower. How can I make this faster? I understand that `Python` cannot achieve the same efficiency as Java but 6 hours compared to 6 minutes seems too much of a difference. Maybe I should be using a different data structure/ functions? I am using `Python 2.7` and `PTVS` IDE.

Adding a minimum working example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed = 0

#Creating a dummy data object - Series within Series
alt = pd.Series(np.array([ 0.25, 0.50,  0.75,  1.00]), index=np.arange(1,5))
data = pd.Series([alt]*1500, index=np.arange(1,1501))

#Creating dataFrame - 
nRows = 200000
d = {'ID1': np.random.randint(1500, size=nRows) + 1
     ,'RAND': np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=nRows)}
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(d)

#Function
def getData(ID1, randomDraw): 
    dataID2 = data[ID1]
    value = dataID2.index[np.searchsorted(dataID2, randomDraw, side='left').iloc[0]]
    return value

dataFrame['ID2'] = np.vectorize(getData)(dataFrame['ID1'], dataFrame['RAND'])
```

Comment: Try setting the index on the ID values this should speed the lookup significantly

Comment: It is indexed on ID values.

Comment: plz show the related code where you apply `getData` over the data-frame

Comment: you should show what your actual problem is. it looks like you need to do a simple merge.

Comment: @Jeff: It is a Monte Carlo prediction procedure - for a random draw [`RAND`] I am looking up the probability density `data[ID1]` and seeing which of the alternatives set of `ID2`s is chosen

Comment: my point is you can probably do the entire thing in a vectorized way. Ideally show an output of what you are looking for.

Comment: @Jeff: Added a minimum working example. I have set nrows in the data frame to 200000 for the example.

Comment: the method below is quite performant even on a very large set. 200k rows takes 217ms (on my machine). Its on the order of the number of groupings you have, and not on the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get a better performance with this code:

```
>>> def getData(ts):
...     dataID2 = data[ts.name]
...     i = np.searchsorted(dataID2.values, ts.values, side='left')
...     return dataID2.index[i]
... 
>>> dataFrame['ID2'] = dataFrame.groupby('ID1')['RAND'].transform(getData)
```

Comment: Great code - works really fast as the lookup order is not on `groupby` levels. Would it be possible to extend this to multi-column grouping? Say `ID0` and `ID1` with the `dataID2` being `data[ID0][ID1]`.

Comment: @RazorXsr yes, but would be slower because of number of groups. You may also need to update to master, see [this patch](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8128)

Comment: OK. So for a multicolumn case I converted `dataID2 = data[ts.name[0]][ts.name[1]]` since the ts.name object becomes a tuple. That is the way to go right?

Comment: @RazorXsr `data[ts.name]` should work by itself. you can pass a tuple to a series with multi-index

Comment: Can I update to master by using `git clone git://github.com/pydata/pandas.git` and then running `python setup.py install`? I do not see the same performance levels as what @Jeff reports - maybe because your patch is not yet in my build version.

Comment: @RazorXsr look at `dataFrame.groupby(...).ngroups` under both single and multi-column. the processing time should be proportional to this number. I think Jeff run-time was for a single column.

Comment: Yeah - I have 40066 groupings. Takes roughly 2.5 hours which adds up. Thanks - the code change shaved my run-time by more than half. Now I am off looking to see if I can economize elsewhere. :)